# Polymer: How to add event listeners to custom polymer element under conditional template

Tags: polymer

I have a custom element `<y-list>` which fires an event `'item-selected'`
i am using this element in another custom element and when i try to add eventlistener to this element

```
<dom-module id="my-list">
 <template is="dom-if" if="{{show}}">
    <y-list list="{{list}}">
    </y-list>
    <hr>
 </template>
</dom-module>

Polymer({

is: 'my-list',

properties: {

  show: {
    type:Boolean,
    value:function() {
        return false
    }
  },
  list: {
    type:Array,
    value:[]
  }
},
ready: function(){
},
attached: function(){
   this.querySelector('y-list').addEventListener('item-selected', function(e){
   console.log(e.detail);
}   
});
```

i am getting the error
`Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

but if i remove `dom-if` condition or use `hidden$` i am able to find the element and add the eventlistener and listen to `item-selected` event

I know that attached is called after ready so i am adding event listener in attached but i am unable to find the element even if i set the `show` attribute to `true` for `<my-list>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the expression of the `dom-if` is `false` the content doesn't exist. In this case it works better to bind `show` to a class to hide the content usin CSS instead of removing it.  Hidden content exists and can be accessed using `this.$` or `this.$$`

`this.querySelector('y-list')` selects elements in the light DOM (projected using `<content>`). It's better to use `Polymer.dom(this).querySelector()` anyway.

To select from the elements template use `this.$.someId`, `this.$$('some-selector')` or `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector ()`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to add listener is [using "on-event"](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#annotated-listeners):

```
<y-list list="{{list}}" on-item-selected="item_selected"></y-list>
```