# set vaadin-combo-box label and value properly in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, vaadin

i try to implements this example [this](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/latest/vaadin-combo-box/demo/objects.html) into polymer since i need to display label's into input.

i just tried

1. html :

```html
    <div id='comp' class="item">
        <form id="formC">   
 <div class="item-label edit">
   <iron-ajax url="/url" last-response="{{resp}}" auto></iron-ajax>

   <vaadin-combo-box id="Box" name="Box" selected-item="{{label}}" 
   placeholder="Please select" items="[[resp]]" item-value-path="label" 
   item-label-path="label" value$='[[data.label]]' name='label' > 
   </vaadin-combo-box>
 </div>                                                                
 <div class="item-valu edit">
      <input size="8" name="valu" value$='[[data.valu]]'>
 </div>
        </form>             
    </div>
```

2. script

```js
        ready(){
            const combobox = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('vaadin-combo- 
     box');
            combobox.items = [
    {label: 'One', nilai: 1},
    {label: 'Two', nilai: 2},
    {label: 'Three', nilai: 3}
  ];
        combobox.addEventListener('selected-item-changed', function() {
         alert("selected-item-change" + JSON.stringify(combobox.selectedItem));
        });
         combobox.addEventListener('value-changed', function() {
         alert("value-change" + combobox.nilai );         
        });
        }
```

on combobox `addEventListener` there's an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` but the error is from `queryselector`

**update 1.** : querySelector success with Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector

**update 2.** : still not understood why combobox.nilai 'undifined'

**update 3.** : it works combobox.selectedItem.nilai ^^ thx god, thx everyone .. now i just need to inject the value

Comment: Why are you using `$this` and not `this`? and who do you expect `$this.$.comp` to be?

Comment: u rite, i just edit my code, hope more clear to understand

Comment: Have you checked examples from here? Under [Allow custom Values](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/html-examples) Maybe you could try the `customElements.whenDefined('vaadin-combo-box').then(function() {` block

Comment: And what about `this.$.comp`? What is the component?

Comment: @masbrojo  a little more context would have helped.. I guess that by this.$.comp you are trying to get that div by ID.. note that this doesn't work for elements that are conditionally rendered (if it's part of an if, for example).. so you can try to replace `this.$.comp` with `this.shadowRoot.getElementById('comp')` to see if it's any different

Comment: @masbrojo and aside from that, a different problem you might have would be with `document.querySelector`.. if you are in shadowDom context you need to query in your shadowRoot, not on a document level..

Comment: yup, my first step is to make querySelector, i change to Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('vaadin-combo-box'); and it work's :) .. now i need, to extract 'selected value' and store it into input text

Answer (score 1):

Does `hmtl` mentioned above located under a`<template>`? In other words, are you creating a Shadow DOM?

If so, by `document.querySelector('vaadin-combo-box');`  you are looking for combobox in the "light" DOM and apparently there is no combobox there, so `null` is returned. Consequentially, the error is thrown, when you try to add a listner to `null`

But otherwise, what is a component with the `comp` id? You would need to access your combobox in the same way.

There are discussions on similar topic here:

- [Polymer: How to add event listeners to custom polymer element under conditional template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517310/polymer-how-to-add-event-listeners-to-custom-polymer-element-under-conditional)
- [Polymer automatic node finding with dynamic id value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588708/polymer-automatic-node-finding-with-dynamic-id-value)
- [How to query elements within shadow DOM from outside in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629492/how-to-query-elements-within-shadow-dom-from-outside-in-dart)
- [Github : this.$ vs. this.shadowRoot.querySelector](https://github.com/Polymer/old-docs-site/issues/2321)

Also, examples from official documentation might be helpful : [Handle and fire events](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events)

Comment: i knew the example i'm refer not for polymer, since not found how to implements in polymer .. i just edit my code @anasmi

Comment: Can you put your whole html page?